# What are all the Maven constructs that reference JDK compiler version?

Tags: maven, java

I have a massive Java 6 migration planned for Maven projects that are currently using JDK4 and JDK5.

In doing so, i'd like to script as much as possible. One thing I'd like to script is to replace all Maven references to a JDK4 or JDK5 to JDK6.

The question is, what are all the ways a Maven file can reference JDK?

Here are the ones I know of, listed as XPath's:

1. `//plugin/artifactId[.='maven-compiler-plugin']`
2. `//maven.compiler.source`
3. `//maven.compiler.target`
   EDIT: Found another one
4. `/project/profiles/profile/activation/jdk`
   EDIT: User added one
5. The `aspectj-maven-plugin` has source and target configuration.

Am I missing any?

Comment: The `aspectj-maven-plugin` has `source` and `target` configuration.